# Get all hardisk list (/dev/sd*)Using command line

Tags: linux, command-line, hard-disk

I need to get all the hardisk connected to my PC like,

```
 /dev/sda
 /dev/sdb
 /dev/sdc
```

later I have to use it in script and monitor using `iostat`

I alrady found `fdisk` command, it seems  to be hard  for me to extract all the device from the output of `fdisk` using `grep`.

Is there any simple way ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

easier than fdisk for your purpose is lsblk:

```
$ lsblk --nodeps
NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk
sdb    8:16   0 298.1G  0 disk
sr0   11:0    1    12M  0 rom
```

or if you just want the drives:

```
$ lsblk --nodeps -n -o name
sda
sdb
sr0
```

Comment: So I have to add /dev/ with the result manually.........?

Comment: yes, sorry to make it so hard, it's some homework for you ;-)

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply....I already completed the homework... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
blkid | awk -F":" '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Actually I don’t need partition only device, like sda,sdb,sdc etc